# Mockk: How to mock object id being generated when object is saved (answers + vararg)

Tags: kotlin, testing, mockk

In my test I need to mock a situation, when new object is saved into database using entity manager (`em`) and during that process, `id` property of that object is set to auto-incremented id of that row in database. I would like to set that `id` property to my own value that I could match later in the test.

I'm using mockk 1.9.3 and kotlin 1.4.0.

So far I have this:

```
val myVal = 123

every { 
     em.persist(any<MyObj>()) 
} answers {
     firstArg<MyObj>().id = myVal
     // return of the persist method
     em
}
```

**Edit:** The `em.persist` method looks like this, problem is probably related to first argument being vararg.

```
open fun persist(vararg o: Any?): T {
    o.forEach { doThePersist(it) }
    return this as T
}
```

But when I try to run that code, I get:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class MyObj
```

Looks like the problem is in the `firstArg` call. If I place a breakpoint on that line, it will reach it and stop there, the exception occurs when I try to evaluate `firstArg<MyObj>()`.

In documentation I was able to find only example using simple Int or example on how to match varargs. Any ideas why the  `ClassCastException` is thrown or how to handle the varargs properly in `answers` section?

Comment: vararg is basically an array with some magic around. Will it work with `(firstArg<Array<Object>()[0] as MyObj).id = myVal` or `firstArg<Array<MyObj>()[0].id = myVal`?

Comment: You are right, there is an array in the first argument of the lambda and that's why I was not able to cast the first argument and obtained the ClassCastException. Tested it and it works, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As *Михаил Нафталь* pointed out in his comment, if the mocked method uses varargs, the arguments are passed into `answers` lambda as an array in the first argument. This solution works for my case:

```
val myVal = 123

every { 
     em.persist(any<MyObj>()) 
} answers {
     val myObj = firstArg<Array<*>>()[0].id as MyObj
     myObj.id = myVal
     // return of the persist method
     em
}
```

I don't have to use special matcher for varargs in `every` section, as I need to match only the first argument in my case.

Maybe there is more elegant way of handling varargs in the `answers` section, but I was not able to find any in the docs. Improvement tips welcome :)